# **UPDATED** Why is my image not showing in my UIWebView popover?

Tags: html, core-data, ios6

I have an iPad app (XCode 4.6, iOS 6.2, CoreData, ARC and Storyboards).  In the CoreData store, I have an image.

I have written the image to the tmp directory on the iPad.  This is the code:

```
    //  create a temporary file to hold the image
NSString *tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
UIImage *custImage = [UIImage imageWithData:client.aClientImage];  //  get the image
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(custImage) writeToFile:tmpDir atomically:YES];  //  write the image to tmp/file

// Create file manager
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSLog(@"\n\ntmp directory: %@", [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:tmpDir error:&error]);
```

The NSLog shows nothing!

I have a UIPopover in which I display some data which includes the image. I am able to get the image from my CoreData store, but in my HTML, it's not showing up.  This is my HTML:

```
    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"<html> \n"
                        "<head> \n"
                        "<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
                        "body {font-family: \"Verdana\"; font-size: 12;}\n"  //  font family and font size here
                        "</style> \n"
                        "</head> \n"
                        "<body><h2>%@ %@</h2>"
                        "<p>email: %@<p>phone: %@<p>services: %@<p><img src=\"%@\"/>"  
                        "</body> \n"
                        "</html>",nil),
                        client.aClientFirstName,
                        client.aClientLastName,
                        client.aClientEMail,
                        client.aClientPrimaryPhone,
                        appt.aServices,
                        @"tmpDir/custImage"];
```

Any idea why the image is not showing?

Comment: What kind of data is stored in `client.aClientImage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're attempting to use an `<img>` element but you're filling in its `src` attribute with the value of a transformable Core Data attribute. These don't work the same way-- `img` expects a URL pointing to an image, and your attribute is providing a `UIImage`.

The most straightforward way to deal with this is to write the image to a file and then make the `img` tag point at that file.

You might also be able to make this work by using something like `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM0AAAD..."` instead of what you have, assuming you can get the formatting correct. You probably want the raw un-transformed `NSData` object rather than the `UIImage`. This is probably a little more work, but avoids writing temporary image files.

Comment: Well, now you're asking a very different question than you were at first. You're not getting anything in the NSLog because you can't write to NSTemporaryDirectory, because **it is a directory** and that directory is still empty. You could create a file in that directory, but you didn't. You should check the return value of `writeToFile:atomically:`.

Comment: Working like  a champ!  Thank you so much... SD